# How to get the overall size of S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to get the overall size of s3 bucket.
When I check in the S3 metrics I can see the Storage size is segregated based on storage type. Is there any way to get a complete size of s3 bucket.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the bucket in the AWS S3 console, select all the objects / folders at the top level, click actions, and choose "calculate total size".

[image: S3 total size]

You'll get a page that looks something like this

[image: S3 size]